# How remember in localstorage a appended div and display it after reload / change page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with my code, because I try to do a visible appended div after refresh page or if someone go for another page.

In file .txt is code to run customer chat Facebook on my page.

My code looks like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.w-iconbox.iconpos_left.style_default.color_primary.no_text.ico-fbm').one('click', function (e) {
        $('<div class="facebook-chat"></div>').load("/fbchat.txt").appendTo("body")
        localStorage.setItem("fb-opened", $('.facebook-chat').html());
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('fb_dialog_mobile').click();
        }, 4000);
    })
    $('.facebook-chat').html(localStorage.getItem("fb-opened"));
})
```

Problem is that when I go for another page or refresh page, the chat div disappears -

how could I fix it to keep it in localstorage e.g. throught 5 hours?

Comment: localStorage only clears when the user clears it, manually or if they are in a private session possibly, or when you logically remove it yourself.  If you are not doing any of those things, the value will still be there.

Comment: you're probably looking for `$(...).on(...)` and not `$(...).one(...)`

Comment: Okey, but how can I keep in localstorage that div?

Answer (score 0):

Just syntax. You're using `one` and not `on`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.w-iconbox.iconpos_left.style_default.color_primary.no_text.ico-fbm').one('click', function (e) {
        $('<div class="facebook-chat"></div>').load("/fbchat.txt").appendTo("body")
        localStorage.setItem("fb-opened", $('.facebook-chat').html());
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('fb_dialog_mobile').click();
        }, 4000);
    })
    $('.facebook-chat').html(localStorage.getItem("fb-opened"));
})
```

Comment: Okey, but it still doesn't keep this div in localstorage... Div disappears after refres page or change subpage...